# Doctrine(Symfony4) is storing data as invalid HEX values

Tags: symfony, utf-8, doctrine, symfony4

When I was about to deploy my Symfony4 app in ubuntu 18 php7.1-fpm + apache I execute some commands to load default data and some fixtures. The problem is that always receive `SQLSTATE[22021]: Character not in repertoire: 7 ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xcd 0x73` In the entities I noticed that are the fields which are mapped as array, json, or simple_array.

Here is an example of one of those fields value:

```
\x65\x6d\x70\x72\x65\x73\x61\x20\x64\x65\x20\x6
  1\x73\x65\x67\x75\x72\x61\x6d\x69\x65\x6e\x74\x6f\x20\x6c\x6f\x67\xcd\x73\x74\x69\x63\x6f\x20\x61\x6c\x20\x74\x61\x62\x61\x63\x6f
```

That is the value for an array of string.

The database config is setted to UTF-8 also the php.ini configuration, the database server is created also using UTF-8.

How can I fix this? I've created the database several times but the same results remains.

Thanks in advance!!

> UPDATE

When I repeat the process on Windows none of this happens...

> UPDATE

Here the complete crash log

```
[2019-10-08 15:21:26] doctrine.DEBUG: INSERT INTO ext_log_entries (id, action, logged_at, object_id, object_class, version, data, username) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) {"1":2042,"2":"create","3":"2019-10-08 15:21:24","4":2042,"5":"App\\Entity\\SeaShipment","6":1,"7":{"manifest":"0323/2019","dmNumber":null,"arrivedAt":"2019-09-16 23:00:00","companyName":"MAQUIMPORT","agencyName":"MINAGRI","contractNumber":null,"merchandiseDescription":null,"countryName":null,"dmNumberAt":null,"etaAt":null,"funderName":null,"customerName":null,"empoweredName":null,"buyerName":null,"docsReceivedAt":null,"originalDocsReceivedAt":null,"billingDeliveredAt":null,"funderBilling":null,"deliveredCustomerAt":null,"isUpdatable":null,"createdFromIp":null,"lastUpdatedFromIp":null,"createdBy":null,"lastUpdatedBy":null,"createdAt":"2019-10-08 15:21:20","lastUpdatedAt":"2019-10-08 15:21:20","deletedAt":null,"seaShipmentType":null,"bl":"2019-M-001147","destinationDock":"TCM","isReleasedHouse":true,"isReleasedMaster":true,"isLocked":false,"isEnabled":true,"daysWithoutDm":0,"daysInTcm":3,"location":"B06","weight":8562,"yard":null,"cabotage":null,"transferedAt":"2019-09-16 14:25:00","transferedTo":"(binary value)","containerNumber":"MAGU5169507","containerType":"HC","containerDimention":40,"lastMarielReportAt":"2019-09-19 23:00:00","shippingCompanyName":"NIRINT","isActive":true,"shipName":null,"journey":null,"originDock":null,"blAt":null,"correspondentName":null,"forwarderName":null,"downloadUngroupAt":null,"beDeliveredAt":null,"packageQuantity":null,"shippingCompany":{"id":26}},"8":null} []
```

For other similar data or transactions before this one the problem is not happening

Answer (score 0):

Can it be that your database doesn't accept cyrillyc/arabic etc alphabets ?
If yes that may help (if you use mysql):

Add to file etc/mysql/my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8mb4_bin
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
character-set-server = utf8mb4
skip-character-set-client-handshake

[client]
default-character-set   = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set   = utf8mb4

After that :

sudo service mysql restart 
then drop database and create it from scratch.
```

Comment: It does support it because the same DB server is installed on windows and the same data is used but this exception is not raised when running on windows. Also I have configured the UTF8 for postgres

Comment: Postgres has [support for different charsets](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/multibyte.html#id-1.6.10.5.7)